# Building error CM bits

Tags: android, makefile, kernel, porting, cyanogenmod

While building the bits of CyanogenMod, I kept receiving the error saying 'unknown type userdata_block_device' from a line from init_shell.te. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Give us the whole init_shell